# How to add context menu items on top of WinForm/ActiveX (hosted by WindowsFormsHost) control's own context menu in WPF

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, windowsformshost

We are creating some WPF UserControl which will utilize some WinForms or ActiveX control by using a WindowsFormsHost. For example, in one UC we have such code:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1" Height="Auto" MinHeight="400" MinWidth="400">
    <viewer:ReportViewer x:Name="viewerInstance" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

where the ReportViewer can be found in Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.

In another UC the code is like this:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1" Height="Auto" MinHeight="400" MinWidth="400">
    <AxOWC:AxPivotTable x:Name="pivotTable" />               
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

where the AxPivotTable can be found in AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.Owc11

Both ReportViewer and AxPivotTable controls have their own context menu which include many use functionality. I'd like to keep them. But I also need to add some new functions. In another word, I want to design an enhanced context menu, with the default context menu being part of it, and my customized menu items being other parts .

And here comes the problem: I really don't know where to add my customized context menu items. I tried to add a context menu object to WindowsFormsHost. But the result is this customized menu will not be showed at all. I further set the WindowsFormsHost.ContextMenu.IsOpen to true, and this time the result is my customized menu will shadow the default context menu of the controls.

I also try to add the menu items from code-behind. For example, the ReportViewer derives from WindowsForms (not WPF assembly), which has a member called ContextMenu. But when I check viewInstance.ContextMenu.MenuItems, I see it actually has ZERO count collection, which means the default context menu doesn't exist on this level. So how can I find the default context menu and add my customized menu items then?

Comment: You can't extend these context menus, they are baked inside the code for these controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't overlap WPF content with non WPF content (unless you are using D3DImage)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what do you mean by "overlap"? It is a somehow blur word so I don't know what exactly you mean. The controls are all derived from System.Windows.Forms.Control. So my idea was to find the Control object, which has a member called ContextMenu, and add customized menu items to it(not trying to make a WPF context menu and make them co-exist). But the problem is the default context menu doesn't exist in this level either

Comment: I am just going back through your question. And the more I think about it. I am going to suggest a different approach. Why not build out your winform type control with your enhancements and what not as a winform control and then embed that in wpf.

Comment: @TYY do you now which Element of an ReportViewer contains the default ContextMenu? Because ReportViewer.ContextMenu == null so it isn't the play's where this ContextMenu is hide.